Can a bevel gearbox be used where the housing also rotates?
We are in the process of designing a custom machine, in which power from a motor has to be distributed to 4 shafts, while the axis of the shafts themselves rotate around a central axis. I hope it is clear from the picture attached.

For this purpose, we need a suitable gearbox. At the present moment, we are looking at a 4-way bevel gearbox, (again attached as picture). From the theory I know, this should theoretically work, since the housing of the gearbox can rotate in the central axis, and the shafts can rotate in their axes.

But I think the gearboxes are not designed with such an application in mind. The usual use case is to fix/mount the housing to a stationary body.
So my question is, first of all, do you see any problems with this application, and are there other/special gearboxes that are designed specifically for this purpose?

What about hydraulic motors?

We hadn't thought about that, how exactly would it be implemented? I am skeptical because we need the power on a shaft which itself rotates, so how do we get the fluid flow from stationary frame to rotation frame

Hollow shaft is one possibility, but only you know the real detail...

Hmm...that is one idea. We will explore in that way if this one is a dead end

Is there any constraint on how fast the output shafts spin around the input shaft's axis? Obviously, if the housing rotates at the same speed as the input shaft, the output shafts won't rotate around their own axes at all. But any load on the output shafts will create a torque on the housing. You need to figure out what controls that balance of power.
